# UITextView text sometimes not filling all space in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I'm pulling data from the Twitter API and have my table cells set up to contain a UITextView to display the tweet. I'm having a problem where sometimes the text will only take up a small part of the available space before wrapping, like in this image:

[image: Image showing the problem]

But if I go click back on the navigation controller, then reload the data it works as it should:

[image: This is what it should look like]

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Here is how my table view is set up:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let tweets = timeline?.tweets {
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if timeline == nil  {
            return 0
        } else {
            if let _timeline = timeline {
                return _timeline.tweets!.count
            }
        }
        
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.TweetTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! TweetTableViewCell
            
        if let _timeline = timeline {
            
            if let tweet = _timeline.tweets?[indexPath.row] {
                cell.tweet = tweet
                cell.tweetTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
                cell.tweetTextView.sizeToFit()
                cell.tweetTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
            }
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

And this is my TableViewCell:

```
  class TweetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileTwitterUsername: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mediaImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likesCountLabel: UILabel!
    

    var tweet: Tweet? {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        if let tweet = tweet {
            
            mediaImageView.isHidden = true

            let profileImageOriginalSizeUrl = tweet.user.profile_image_url_https.replacingOccurrences(of: "_normal", with: "")
            
            if let profileImageOriginalSizeUrl = URL(string: profileImageOriginalSizeUrl) {
                profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: profileImageOriginalSizeUrl, completed: nil) // Get image from cache
            }
            
            roundProfileImage()
           
            profileNameLabel.text = tweet.user.name
            profileTwitterUsername.text = "@\(tweet.user.screen_name)"
 
            tweetTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            tweetTextView.text = tweet.full_text
            
            tweetDateLabel.text = truncateDate(withDate: tweet.created_at)
            
            tweetTimeLabel.text = truncateTime(withDate: tweet.created_at)
        }

        if let media = tweet?.entities?.media?[0].media_url_https {
            
            mediaImageView.isHidden = false
            
            if let mediaImageUrl = URL(string: media) {
                mediaImageView.sd_setImage(with: mediaImageUrl, completed: nil)
            }
            
        }

    }
```

Also if it helps, here is my storyboard which contains the stack view holding the UITextView and UIImageView along with the constraints:

[image: Storyboard and constraints]

Console shows some of these warnings when app is running:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b140004a6a0 h=--& v=--& UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.height == 95.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400045ba0 UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.height == 100   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400045ba0 UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.height == 100   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-08-03 04:57:43.373999+0100 StarChallenge[22459:10425072] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b140004a5b0 h=--& v=--& UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7b4c00045c80 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b140004a600 h=--& v=--& UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.width == 348.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400046e60 H:[UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...']-(30)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7b4c00045c80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400047040 H:|-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7b4c00045c80]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00045ac0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400047090 H:[UIStackView:0x7b4c00045c80]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00045ac0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b140004ae70 'fittingSizeHTarget' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b4c00045ac0.width == 375   (active)>"
)
```

Comment: What does the View Debugger tell you? Any exclamation marks?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the console output

Comment: Well there’s part of your answer. Why you are saying `translates` is `true` is a mystery to me. But then, so is your use of `sizeToFit`. But really, do fire up the View Debugger. I think you’ll find there are further issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b140004a6a0 h=--& v=--& UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.height == 95.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b1400045ba0 UITextView:0x7b740006d600'I'm back with a brand new...'.height == 100   (active)>"
```

You set the constraint height of your TextView = 100. And after the resizing marks, the constrain height is 95.5 which is conflict with the previous value.

- You can try by `remove` or set the priority of your TextView's constraint height to low (250).

Or use `UILabel` instead, you don't have to set the constraint height for the label and don't have to use `AutoresizingMask` & `sizeToFit()` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Your cell is done loading the data into the outlets before auto layout finishes setting up.

```
Override layoutSubviews() {
Super.layoutSubviews
// Call your setup method
}
```

This is called after auto layout does it thing.